# Replace combo box scroll bar with custom scroll bar in C#

Tags: c#, windows, combobox, scrollbar

Can we replace the default scroll bar in the combo box with custom scroll bar?
Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: WinForms? No, not easily. You have to replace most of the logic of the combobox itself (custom dropdown window and then custom scrollbar for a custom list).

Comment: Yup. Need to replace the default combobox list with custom list.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing Andrino's comment "No, not easily"

However there are a few free non-comerical libriaries with improved WinForms controls you can use, such as [VIBlend](http://www.viblend.com/). This may provide some of the functionality you are looking to add yourself.

Some more controls are available here on the [MSDN Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=RootCategory&f%5B0%5D.Value=controls&f%5B0%5D.Text=Controls&f%5B1%5D.Type=CostCategory&f%5B1%5D.Value=Free&f%5B1%5D.Text=Free)